# Jasmine command not found

Tags: zsh, jasmine

I am using zsh (with oh-my-zsh) and rbenv: both installed through homebrew.
I am attempting to get jasmine to run in a standalone app.  After installing the jasmine gem

> gem install jasmine

I tried the

```
jasmine init
```

and received a

> zsh: command not found: jasmine

Do I have to explicitly set a path or something else in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually a bit of an rbenv issue. Rbenv doesn't shim itself into your shell as aggressively as, say, rvm, which means you have to do something like

```
rbenv rehash
```

To get rbenv to update its aliases and make the `jasmine` command available. This only needs to happen the first time you install a gem that has a shell command with it. After that rbenv should update its reference behind the scenes and you should always get the most up to date version.